# Upgrading from Sublime Text 3143 to 3176 results in bold font

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have two installations of portable Sublime Text 3 on my computer: 3143 and 3176. I've ported all my settings, my theme, plugins over to 3176 and everything is perfect except for the default font being bold.

My settings have not changed.

```
"font_face": "Consolas",
"font_size": 11,
```

Inspecting my (custom) theme, nothing suggests it should be bold and that the new version would be sensitive to it.

Nothing in `font_options` seems to help either.

**Old (happy):**

[image: Old]

**New (sad):**

[image: New]

Comment: If you use windows, you may want to check out [this forum post](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/bad-font-rendering-win-3170/36824/4); in a nutshell the font rendering engine was updated and now respects the windows ClearType settings better, which can cause issues like this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [3.1 changelog](https://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-3-point-1):

> Improved text rendering on Windows, now respecting ClearType tuning

Go to `Preferences -> Settings`, then in your user settings add:

```
"font_options": ["dwrite_cleartype_classic"],
"theme_font_options": ["dwrite_cleartype_classic"],
```

If those don't work for you, use `dwrite_cleartype_natural` for each instead.

**Still having trouble?** Make sure `font_face` and `font_size` are as you expect; I had a lower font size for a computer with lower resolution.